# how to get cookies created in javascript

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, cookies, web-crawler

I am having a problem with my crawler.

I was able to log in to a web site but when I try to connect to a specific page it was redirecting me back to the login page.  After some research I realized that there are some cookies set by javascript that my cookie container didn't store.

How can I get those cookies programatically?

Comment: What are you using to parse the HTML your crawler retrieves?

Comment: If the code is simple enough just look cookies/values the javascript sets and add them to the cookie container yourself

Comment: I am using HTTPWEBREQUEST and HTTPWEBRESPONSE and reading the response using StreamReader

and no the code is far from simple I cant just understand what the values of the cookies are...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set them on request as any other cookies.

If your question is "how to figure out is JavaScript set any cookies" - no, you can't generically do it without running complete pages in normal (potentially headless) browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cookies set by javascript on the server with

```
Request.Cookies
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx

To see the value of the cookie prior to sending to the server use Chrome Developer, IE Developer Toolbar or Firebug depending on what browser you are using.